# How to integrate $e^z/z^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

This may be a very basic question.

How to compute the integral $ \int_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z^2} \, dz$, where $\gamma$ is the unit circle? I did it with Cauchy's integral formula for $\int_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z}\,dz$, but how about this one?

Comment: Why is this giving you a problem?

Comment: Can I pick f(z)=e^z/z and use Cauchy's formula?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's legit because f is not defined at 0.

Comment: Is the problem to integrate over the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, it's over the unit circle.

Comment: Then, yes.  Apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Have you seen the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives? (This is a "weaker" version of the residue theorem, in a sense.)

Comment: The integral will not be zero because of the pole.  But the residue theorem is applicable.  Do you know it?

Comment: No, I haven't studied it yet. I know very little beyond Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @Ian, yes it seems the formula for derivatives was what I needed.

Comment: You can deform the contour to exclude the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(z) = e^z$ is analytic inside and on $\gamma$ (in fact, it's entire) and $0$ lies inside $\gamma$. So by Cauchy's differentiation formula,

$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z^2}\, dz = \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^2}\, dz = 2\pi i f'(0) = 2\pi i.$$

Comment: What is the antiderivative of this function? Primitive of $e^z/z^2$?

Comment: @DrPotato The function $e^z/z^2$ has no primitive inside $\gamma$, or else the integral evaluates to zero.

Comment: would $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{z^3}}{z^4}dz$ also be $2\pi i$?

Comment: @anonymous yes, that's right.